# Could not initialize proxy - no Session due to different Thread

Tags: hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0, jpa-2.0

In my Play application, a separate Thread (not bound to any HTTP context, using `JPA.withTransaction`) populates a list of items from a database and stores it via `Cache.set(key, list)` into the Cache.

When the user now requests that list, it's loaded from the Cache. But then I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.SubList[0]->model.Document["caseTypeCtlg"]->model.CaseTypeCtlg_$$_jvste65_3b["caseType"])]]
```

The error appears when calling `Json.toJson(list);`

One solution would be to store the JSON itself to the Cache, but unfortunately I have to manipulate the list after loading it from the Cache.